# C# P/Invoke: native output parameter value won't reach managed code

Tags: c#, c++, pointers, interop, pinvoke

I'm marshalling a native C++ DLL to a C# DLL. I'm not very acknowledged in C/C++, but I've managed to make it work until I got stuck on this problem. Here's a very simplistic code example:

C++

```
PROASADLL __declspec(dllexport) void outTest(int* number){
    int temp = *number + 10;
    number = &temp; //*number = 12
}
```

C#

```
[DllImport("ProAsaNativeDll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern void outTest(ref int number);

public static int OutTest()
{
    int number = 2;
    outTest(ref number);
    return number; //number = 2
}
```

Please notice that I'm my real scenario, I'm trying to get this to work with a pointer to pointer to struct but I decided to leave it out as it is not a marshalling issue; not even this simple code will work. The C++ code works but I wouldn't rule out being dumb and having a problem there: like I said, I don't know much C/C++.

The number variable value in the C# wrapper method won't change. Please help.

Comment: It is bad C++ code.  That never gets better when you pinvoke it.  Make it work from a C++ test program first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are getting a bad result because in your C++ code you are actually changing the parameter `number` by setting it to another pointer.

I believe that your change will only be visible in your function `outTest`'s scope.

However, if you change the value where the pointer ... points... that's should be a different story. Pretty much like this:

```
*number = *number + 10;
```

EDIT: This bit is not tested. Oh... and also... I haven't written anything in C++ for ages. Might as well be totally wrong.

Comment: Like riding a bike

Comment: @Jacobr365 Yeah... All's well and neat... Until you fall down and "bend" your nose :)

Comment: Nice! Like I said, C++ isn't my forte, but I see both "what you did there" and where I was wrong. Many thanks!

Comment: @S.O. That's how we all learn... Keep up the good work! Cheers!